# Pluralizing shortened words

Tags: apostrophe

I'm stumped at [this forum reply](http://www.treehugger.com/slideshows/environmental-policy/think-air-quality-regulations-dont-matter-look-pittsburgh-1940s/#comment-904805945) which states that the contracted plural of "regulation" is "reg's".

"Cigarettes" is shortened to "cigs", as far as i know, but perhaps that's because "a cig" is a common term.

How about this:

> The makings of a beautiful friendship.

Can it be

> The makin's of a beautiful friendship.

or

> The makins of a beautiful friendship.

?

Comment: I'm sure you're right about common contractions not 'needing' apostrophes. We never use 'phone or 'bus nowadays. Plurals of unusual contractions do seem to include apostrophes more often, but the picture is far from clear - see the Ngram for cigs,cig's,makins,makin's at http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cigs%2Ccig%27s%2Cmakins%2Cmakin%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share= . Fwiw, I'd choose _makin's_. And _makin'_.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd contract out the single "g" in making.  Are you going for a colloquial sound?  I was taught to use the apostrophe for omitted letters, FWIW.

Comment: Yes, but it was mostly the only example i could easily come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a [Google search](http://rdd.me/oxm5bf3h) for "regs" and found substantial evidence that "regs" is a standard abbreviation for the plural of "regulations".

Pluralizing the abbreviation of "makings" as "makins" isn't possible simply because it's misleading. There is no common noun "makin", but there are proper nouns "Makin". "Makin'" is the word you want to pluralize, so it would have to be "*makin*'s": "He has the *makin*'s of a champion".

Comment: I'd add [this link](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cigs%2Ccig%27s%2Cmakins%2Cmakin%27s%2Cregs%2Creg%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) to show the history and popularity of all disputed terms, and [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22regs%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1998,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) to note that "regs" still means "regulations".

Comment: What? Makin? how is that a noun? It's a Japanese group of islands http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makin or some politician - the nGram hardly shows any "makin's of" or "makins of"

Comment: @mplungjan: _Proper nouns_ are names, like "Bill", "Rita", "Sally", & "Barack". And Makin Island, & the [Division of Makin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_of_Makin). _Common nouns_ are the names of things, like "tire", "wheelbarrow", "hose", & "nose". Makin is also an unincorporated community in the US state of Indiana. You won't find many instances of "_makin_'s of". It's strictly dialogue. People will say it, but not many will write it, I'm sure.

Comment: Note, once again, that this is all about a spelling and pronunciation problem brought on by overly zealous but totally unearned faith in the power of written language. The plural of /rɛɡ/ is /rɛɡz/; this has been the case since there was a word /rɛɡ/ to have a plural of, no matter how it was or wasn't spelled. Or punctuated. This is all about technology, and is about as natural as double-clutching.

Comment: Right, apologies for the noun part, I was misguided by the "makin's of a champion"

Comment: `makins` was more popular than `makin's` from 1800 to 1890 and 1975 to 1983, but lost ground to `makin's` [since 1997](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=makins%2Cmakin%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2013&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=). Yet Google Books [couldn't find](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=makin%2Cmakin%27&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) `makin'`. Silly search engines.